# Ansible not able to install virtualenv

Tags: python, ansible, virtualenv

I am trying to install and create a virtualenv using this script

```
- name: Installing virtualenv
  pip: name=virtualenv state=present

- name: Create python virtualenv
  command: virtualenv {{user_home_path}}/my_venv -p python3.6 creates={{user_home_path}}/my_venv
  become_user: "{{app_user}}"

- name: Create python virtualenv
  command: virtualenv {{user_home_path}}/your_venv -p python3.6 creates={{user_home_path}}/your_venv
  become_user: "{{app_user}}"
```

Error:

```
fatal: [68.183.89.165]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "virtualenv /home/me/my_venv -p python3.6", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2, "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

But it fails saying `/home/me/your_venv` does not exist even though it does. I copied over the command that ansible printed out in the error report and tried it and it passed when I ran it directly.

Why does this fail only via ansible ?

Comment: Have you tried providing full path to virtualenv in your 2nd and 3rd tasks ? Its possible that env var $PATH is not updated with the path containing virtualenv for {{app_user}}, in which case you need to provide the full path.

Comment: it is updated because the error shows the path correctly.

Comment: Try using the shell module instead of command module, and also use quotes like in this example.  shell: "virtualenv {{user_home_path}}/your_venv -p python3.6 creates={{user_home_path}}/your_venv"

Comment: I am confused. The error shows that `/home/go/my_venv` does not exist, but you claim that the error errors that `/home/me/your_venv` does not exist. Which is it? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Tom Sorry that was a typo. I was replacing my actual paths with `me` and missed one. Have fixed it now